# My google cloud VM remote desktop is showing a black screen upon connection

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When I connect to my remote desktop, I just see a black screen. I've tried from my PC, laptop, and mobile. I'm able to connect, but don't see anything. This started yesterday around 2 pm Pacific. Google reported some outage issues, but not specifically with the virtual machine and those issues have been long fixed. Please help. I'm not able to access anything right now.

I tried from different devices and still get the black, blank screen. I also tried switching my internet connection and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Unfortunately, I had to cancel my cloud service. Google doesn't offer support beyond billing. I tried to purchase support for $30/month but ran into an issue. I decided to cancel and purchase VPS with a hosting provider.